# Remove extra duplicate entries in unkeyed table

Tags: kdb, k

I have the following table below and would like to delete all rows that are duplicates. I have created a column dup which counts the number of duplicates.

`delete from table where dup>1` would delete all entries of the duplicate and I would still like 1 entry to remain in my table.

```
ISIN         RIC      BLOOMBERG dup
-----------------------------------
LU1681046006 CWEm.BS  CWEM EB   2
LU1681046006 CWEm.BS  CWE EB    2
LU1681046006 CWEm.BS  CWEM EB   2
LU1681046006 CWEm.BS  CWE EB    2
LU1681046006 CWEm.CHI CWEM IX   2
LU1681046006 CWEm.CHI CWE IX    2
LU1681046006 CWEm.CHI CWEM IX   2
LU1681046006 CWEm.CHI CWE IX    2
LU1681046006 CWE.MI   CWE IM
LU1681046006 WDNR.DE  WDNR GY
```

So the resulting table should look like:

```
ISIN         RIC      BLOOMBERG dup
-----------------------------------
LU1681046006 CWEm.BS  CWEM EB   2
LU1681046006 CWEm.BS  CWE EB    2
LU1681046006 CWEm.CHI CWEM IX   2
LU1681046006 CWEm.CHI CWE IX    2
LU1681046006 CWE.MI   CWE IM
LU1681046006 WDNR.DE  WDNR GY
```

Any idea how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try `distinct <table name>`

This should return you all of the distinct rows of your table

For more info please reference to this link:
https://code.kx.com/q/ref/search/#distinct

Answer (score 4):

I think you may be able to use `distinct` instead of trying to count duplicates.

```
q)td  
a   b 
----- 
kdj 8 
eeg 1 
nce 9 
jog 5 
cih 4 
hkp 6 
aea 6 
blm 1 
ooe 8 
jgj 5 
jgj 5 

q)distinct td
a   b
-----
kdj 8
eeg 1
nce 9
jog 5
cih 4
hkp 6
aea 6
blm 1
ooe 8
jgj 5
```